# Java Applet repaint from another class

Tags: java, applet, awt, paint, keylistener

I am learning Java game development and I am having an issue understanding why the "Robot" is not moving.
I know the issue is with the repaint but I can not figure it out.

please help

Thank

Game Class

```
     public class GameMain extends Applet implements KeyListener  {


private Image image, character;
private Graphics gpx;
private Droid droid;
private URL base;
private static Background bg1, bg2;

@Override
public void init() {

    setSize(800, 480);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);
    Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
    frame.setTitle("My First Game");

    droid = new Droid();
    base = getDocumentBase();
    character = getImage(base, "data/char.png");

}

@Override
public void start() {


    GameThread thread = new GameThread();
    thread.start();
    System.out.println("Thread Started");
}

@Override
public void stop() {


}


@Override
 public void destroy() {

 }
@Override
public void update(Graphics g) {

    if(image == null){
        image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        gpx = image.getGraphics();
    }

    gpx.setColor(getBackground());
    gpx.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    gpx.setColor(getForeground());
    paint(gpx);

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(character, droid.getPositionX() - 61, droid.getPositionY()- 63, this);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {

    switch(key.getKeyCode() ){
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:

        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:

        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        droid.moveLeft();
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
        droid.moveRight();
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
        droid.jump();
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key) {
    switch(key.getKeyCode() ){
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:

        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:

        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        droid.stop();
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
        droid.stop();
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:

        break;
    }
}



@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent key) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 }
```

Thread Class

```
    public class GameThread extends Thread  {

GameMain game;
Droid droid;

private static Background bg1, bg2;

public GameThread(){

    bg1 = new Background(0,0);
    bg2 = new Background(2160, 0);


}



@Override
public void run() {
    game = new GameMain();
    droid = new Droid();
    //Game while loop
    while(true){

        droid.update();
        game.repaint();
    //bg1.update();
    //bg2.update();


    try {
        Thread.sleep(17);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 }


 }
```

Droid Class

```
      public class Droid {

private int positionX = 100;
private int positionY = 382;

private int speedX = 0;
private int speedY = 1;

private boolean jump = false;

    public void update(){

    //Update X Position
    if(speedX < 0){
        positionX += speedX;

    }else if(speedX == 0){
        System.out.println("Do not scroll the background.");
    }else{

        if(positionX <= 150){
            positionX += speedX;

        }else{
            System.out.println("Scroll Background Here");
        }
    }
    //Update Y Position
    if(positionY + speedY >= 382){
        positionY = 382;
    }else{
        positionY += speedY;
    }

    //update Jump

    if(jump == true){
        speedY += 1;

        if(positionY + speedY >= 382){
            positionY = 382;
            speedY = 0;
            jump = false;
        }
    }
}

   public void moveRight(){
speedX = 6;
System.out.println(speedX);
  }

  public void moveLeft(){
speedX = -6;
System.out.println(speedX);
  }

 public void stop(){
speedX = 0;
 }
 public void jump(){
if(jump == false){
    speedY = -15;
    jump = true;
}
   }



public void setPositionX(int positionX){

    this.positionX = positionX;
}

public int getPositionX(){
    return positionX;
}

    public void setPositionY(int positionY){

    this.positionY = positionY;
}

public int getPositionY(){
    return positionY;
}

public void setSpeedX(int speedX){
    this.speedX = speedX;
}

public int getSpeedX(){
    return speedX;
}

public void setSpeedY(int speedY){
    this.speedY = speedY;
}

public int getSpeedY(){
    return speedY;
}


      }
```

Comment: 1- Applet is outdated, you should be using `JApplet`; 2- I'd be very careful using `this.getParent().getParent()`, you may not like the results if you deployed this in a browser...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See this answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the droid you're updating isn't the `droid` you're painting...in fact, the `GameMain` you're repainting isn't the one that is one the screen...

```
public class GameMain extends Applet implements KeyListener {

    //...
    private Droid droid;
    //...

    @Override
    public void init() {
        //...
        droid = new Droid();
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(character, droid.getPositionX() - 61, droid.getPositionY()- 63, this);
    }
```

And then in you `GameThread`;

```
public class GameThread extends Thread {

    GameMain game;
    Droid droid;

    //...

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Created a new GameMain
        game = new GameMain();
        // Created a new Droid...
        droid = new Droid();
        //Game while loop
        while (true) {

            droid.update();
            game.repaint();
            //...
```

You create new instances of `GameMain` and `Droid`, these have no connection what so ever to the screen.

Instead, you should be passing a reference of `GameMain` to the `GameThread` and `GameThread` should be telling `GameMain` to update the game state...

For example...

Add the method `updateGameState`

```
public class GameMain extends Applet implements KeyListener {
    //...

    public void updateGameState() {
        droid.update();
        repaint();
    }

    //...
```

Then in `GameMain`'s start method, pass a reference of `GameMain` to `GameThread`...

```
GameThread thread = new GameThread(this);
thread.start();
```

Then in `GameMain`, store the reference you are passed and remove any reference to `Droid`

```
public class GameThread extends Thread {

    //...
    private GameMain gameMain;

    public GameThread(GameMain gameMain) {
        this.gameMain = gameMain;
        //...
```

Then in `GameTread#run`, call `gameMain.updateGameState();`...

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        gameMain.updateGameState();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(17);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note...

1. Applet is outdated, you should be using JApplet
2. I'd be very careful using `this.getParent().getParent()`, you may not like the results if you deployed this in a browser..
3. And when you start using `JApplet`, move you game rendering to something like `JPanel`, overriding it's `paintComponent` method, this will give you automatic double buffering and use the [Key binding API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener`.  It's more easily, programmatically, updatable and doesn't suffer from the same focus related issues as `KeyListener`

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining the answer and not just resolving it for me.

Comment: it makes perfect sense what you explained